# How to get a specific row out of a for() loop. It keeps looping when it should stop

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Sheet1Data.length; i++) {
```

And I'm trying to get i when it equals a specific row, the row has to be the row where two values on two different spreadsheets don't match, which i get like this.

```
 var s1data = Sheet1Data[i][0];
 var s2data = Sheet2Data[i][0];
if (s1data != s2data){
      var falseRow = i+1
}
```

the Sheet data is all the values of the range of the sheet.  So as the if function counts down using the loop it looks like:

0: Aang=Aang

1: Korra=Korra

2: Sakka!=Toph -> var falseRow = 2+1=3

The reason i add that plus 1 is to change the number from that whole 0=first row thing to an integer other functions understand..
When it gets that false row it chooses to do things with it depending on where the values it found are in the sheet.  For Example:"; ;" represents change in Spreadsheet.

0: Aang; ;Aang

1: Korra; ;Korra

2: Sakka; ;Toph

3: Toph; ;(blank space)

it uses another loop to find where these values are in the other sheet

```
   var s1falseRowARange = s1.getRange(falseRow,1,1,1);
   var s1falseRowAName = s1falseRowARange.getValues();
for (var j = 0; j < Sheet1Data.length; j++) {
   var s1dataj = Sheet1Data[j][0];
   var s2dataj = Sheet2Data[j][0];
   if(s1falseRowAName == s2dataj){
      var s2trueRow = j+1;
}
}
```

it also does this but for sheet2. So it finds where Toph would be in Sheet 2, which is the 4th row so

```
var s1trueRow =j+1;//or 4
```

But there is no Sakka in Sheet2?  So it determines that he isn't there using

```
  if(falseRow > s2trueRow) {
    var fm2t = 'true';
  }
  else if(falseRow < s2trueRow) {
    var fl2t = 'true';
  }
    var s2Rowfound = 'true';
}
  else if(j+1 == s2LastRow && s2Rowfound != 'true'){
     s2.insertRows(falseRow);
     s2.getRange(falseRow,1,1,1).setValue(s1data)
  }
function insertCell(cellRange) {
  var sos = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet1");
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  s1.getRange(cellRange).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}

function deleteCell(cellRange){
  var sos = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Sheet1");
  var sas = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(sos);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = ss.getActiveSheet();
  s1.getRange(cellRange).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
}
```

the Var s2Rowfound was never equal to true.  So it determined he doesn't exist on sheet2 and added him to sheet 2.

This is where My issue finally comes up!
falseRow is equal to the loop value i.  So as it adds this new row, the loop function may still be working on accident which causes incidents like this after adding Sakka to the list:

0: Aang; ;Aang

1: Korra; ;Korra

2: Sakka; ;Sakka

3: Toph; ;(blank space)

4:(blank space); ;Toph

It inserted a Row on the next row, when it shouldn't have.  This has something to do with falseRow being a loop variable i.  And it's not just adding rows, it's also deleting rows(I have a situation where if it doesn't exist on sheet1 it deletes that row).  Sometimes it will work fine, but sometimes it will add or delete rows following the loop. How do I get it to not continue the loop until after it deletes or adds rows to prevent this double adding or double deleting from happening?

**EDIT:**
Okay so I did more testing with it.  It seems like the problem might lie more with the `deleteCell()` and `insertCell()` and `insertRows()` functions. There are hiccups where it will repeat itself for no apparent reason.  I may have to make another question that revolves more around this than the loops.  But in case anyone here has any ideas, I'll give you more background on it.

```
if(j+1 == s1LastRow && fnot1t == 'true' && 'F3' != 'RUNNING'){
          s1.getRange('F3').setValue('RUNNING');
```

I tried many things like setting a Cell to "RUNNING" in the beginning of the function and setting it back to " ". when it was finished with that part.  To prevent it from racing itself.  This at least gave me the benefit of having a visual indicator as to what the function was doing at the time.

```
          var falseRow = falseRowC.getRow();
          s1.getRange('F4').setValue(falseRow);
          var F4 = s1.getRange('F4').getValue();
          s2.deleteRow(F4);
```

I then tried making the falseRow into other types of variables to get it as far away from "i" as possible, thinking that was what was making the errors. This went as far as writing the row into a cell and grabbing that cell's value in place of the row I needed to change.

```
          s1.getRange('C'+F4).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
          Logger.log('Delete row '+F4+' from Mirror Sheet.');
          s1.getRange('F3').setValue('');
        }
```

Here is where the F3 cell turns back to nothing to indicate that this process is finished and to be allowed to perform the process from the start.  You also see the deleteCells function is in here, so how can it perform twice if it's only written once AND this function can't run again until after the RUNNING indicator is turned off?  That is the question.

```
        else if(j+1 == s1LastRow && fnot2t == 'true' && fl1t == 'true' && 'F3' != 'RUNNING') {
          s1.getRange('F3').setValue('RUNNING');
          var falseRow = falseRowC.getRow();
          s1.getRange('F4').setValue(falseRow);
          var F4 = s1.getRange('F4').getValue();
          s1.getRange('C' + F4).insertCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
          s1.getRange('C' + F4).setValue('HOME');
          var SRange = s1.getRange(F4,1,1,2);
          var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
          var SData = SRange.getValues();
          s2.insertRows(F4);
          s2.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
          s1.getRange('F3').setValue('');
        }
```

And this is the same process but when it adds rows.  Same problem.  Made F3 = RUNNING to prevent it from running this insertRows process.  But for some reason it adds multiple rows.

Comment: It's unclear to me. Is it just important that all the names appear in both sheets or is the positioning thing also important? And why are you inserting cells rather than appending rows? It would make more sense to me to merely find out what names are missing, append that name, and then sort both pages by name. Would that simplify this for you?

Comment: Is Sheet1 and Sheet2 always the same size?

Comment: What row does your data start on?

Comment: Can you share data sheets?

Comment: @ J.G. All names need to appear on both sheets.  It's because one sheet is the sheet people look at and the second sheet is just there to show the first sheet what changed.  There is a column C on Sheet 1 that is edited using the same row of the difference, and it is changed by people, so I can't have it append over it, because that will reset it, which i don't want. Column C needs to follow, either up or down, with the person it belongs to.  that is why deleting and adding has to be precise. I have it finding the correct row, the issue is it deletes or adds past those rows.

Comment: @ Cooper Sheet1 and Sheet2 are not always the same size.  I once used this to determine if it should add or delete by saying if Sheet1 > Sheet2, than sheet 1 had someone added, so find different row and add to sheet2 and if it's the opposite delete from sheet2.  This worked, but if someone is both added and deleted from the list, it gets confused.  So it's not full proof.  Both sheets start on the same rows, Row 1 is just a header for both of them row 2 down has names.

Comment: Your this loop `for (var j = 0; j < Sheet1Data.length; j++) {
   if(s1falseRowAName == s2data){
      var s2trueRow = j+1;
}
}` doesn't really change anything inside the loop since for every iteration `s1falseRowAName` and `s2data` are the same

Comment: @ Aung49 oof you caught I forgot to add some crucial detail with that one, infact It's more my bad because I didn't change the variable to make it less confusing.  That variable, s2data, isn't actually the same one. with the j loop as with the i loop.  I'm going to update my question to add that tidbit.  Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on the `getValues()` method (link below), it "Returns a two-dimensional array of values, indexed by row, then by column." So when you compare it with `s2dataj`, which is a single value, it might be giving you a problem. Since you set up the range to get the single cell when you call `s1.getRange(falseRow,1,1,1)`, I believe your check should be:

```
if(s1falseRowAName[0][0] == s2dataj){
      var s2trueRow = j+1;
}
```

`getValues()` Documentation Link: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

Comment: I made the change, unfortunately same problem persists.  It double adds a row or double deletes a row.  I've come to the conclusion it might be more related to the insertRow and insert Cell functions.